# Configure Webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin to remove filename

Tags: webpack

I am using `webpack --optimize-minimize` and I notice that the compiled file still has comments with the filename. How do I tell `Webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin` to remove these as well?

Here is the generated file see how the end of the first line starts a comment and it continues to line 3. This is what I want to remove

```
!function(e){function t(n){if(r[n])return r[n].exports;var o=r[n]={exports:{},id:n,loaded:!1};return e[n].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,t),o.loaded=!0,o.exports}var r={};return t.m=e,t.c=r,t.p="",t(0)}([/*!*************************!*\
  !*** ./src/js/index.js ***!
  \*************************/
function(e,t){"use strict";function r(e){return e}Object.defineProperty(t,"__esModule",{value:!0}),t.identity=r}]);%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That comment is called the `pathinfo` and is generated by the `output.pathinfo` property. This can be disabled by removing that option or setting it to false from the webpack config. See the [docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-pathinfo) for more details.

```
output: {
  pathinfo: false
},
```